# How to prove that $GF(p^n)$ contains an element of degree n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am reading Gallian's Algebra book, and I am lapsing on Corollary 2 to Theorem 22.2. The statement goes: "Let $a$ be a generator of the group of nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)$ under multiplication. Then $a$ is algebraic over $GF(p)$ of degree $n$."

I totally understand the proof in which it says $[GF(p)(a):GF(p)]=[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$. But why can we use this argument to show that $a$ is algebraic over $GF(p)$? I only know that we can deduce $[F(a):F]=n$ if $a$ is algebraic over $F$ with minimal polynomial of order $n$, but not the other way around...

Comment: You probably have also covered the part that if $[F(a):F)]$ is infinite if and only if $a$ is transcendental. So here $a$ is necessarily algebraic of **some** degree. And that result then tells you that the degree has to be equal to $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element of $GF(p^n)$ is algebraic over $GF(p)$.  Indeed, if $x\in GF(p^n)$ is nonzero, then $x^m=1$ for some $m$, and so $x$ is a root of the polynomial $x^m-1$.  (I'll leave the case that $x=0$ to you.)

Comment: Is the case trivially true?

Answer (score 2):

Any finite field extension is necessarily algebraic, so $a$ as the generator of this extension is certainly algebraic.